# Android Retrofit 1.9 return ListString upon success

Tags: java, android, rest, background, retrofit

I searched similar questions like this but sadly I found them really confusing and also I'm still new on using Android and Retrofit.

I have a contact list JSON here

```
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/
```

And already working List but then I wanted to handle the Retrofit process to another class so I can just call it whenever I want. I have the MainActivity calling for the UI and the RetrofitHandler which handles the success and failure method.

Here is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

//note i just simplifiend my code a little

private List<Contacts> contacts;
public String[] itemer;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RetrofitHandler retrofitHandler = new RetrofitHandler();

    itemer = retrofitHandler.getContacts(this);

    if (itemer != null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,itemer[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }

}
```

And here is my HandlerClass

```
ublic class RetrofitHandler {
public String[] item;
public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://api.androidhive.info";
public List<Contacts> contacts;

public String[] getContacts(final Context context) {
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ROOT_URL).build();
    ContactsAPI api = adapter.create(ContactsAPI.class);

    api.getContacts(new Callback<Contacts>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Contacts contacts, Response response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            MainActivity update = new MainActivity();
            List<Contact> contactList = contacts.getContacts();


            item = new String[contactList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {

                item[i] = contactList.get(i).getName();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    return item;
}
```

My problem is it runs smoothly with no error on LogCat. Unfortunately the Toast on the mainactivity won't appear.

Comment: being a network call, there could be main thread and background thread issue, 
So why can't you toast from end of  success function.
Also , check if response you are receiving is null or not

Comment: @mohitsharma Well the toast upon success is what i accomplished but originally i want to put may items on a listview from the main activity the items upon success is not null i tested it with the toast

Comment: try to check on: if your condition is executing or not,
try put a Println inside if block and change the  condition to itemer.length/size

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because of asynchronous nature of the request/response. Success or Failure callbacks fires upon response, which is happen in asynchronous manner. So basically **your method returns before that happens**, it means your item is null. You have to use synchronous mechanism or you have to check [MVP pattern](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/) which gives perfect solution for your problem. See below is an example of using synchronous call (I've not tested it, but it should work).

```
public List<Contacts> getContacts(){
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ROOT_URL).build();
    ContactsAPI api = adapter.create(ContactsAPI.class);
    return api.getContacts();
}
```

See this [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests) to get more idea. I suggest you to move to retrofit 2 which is much more greater than retrofit 1.